# Getting status code 304 on a get request with axios using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios, http-status-code-304

I have a `get` request in my `Redux Async Thunk`. After calling `get` to my node.js express server it sends a `304` status code, for some reason I can't get my data.

```
const userTokenAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/shoes',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  },
});

userTokenAxios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (response.data.errorMessage === 'jwt expired') {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }
});

export const getShoesAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'shoes/getShoesAsync',
  async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await userTokenAxios.get('/');
      console.log(response);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

Its being called from my homepage:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getShoesAsync());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

But I can't get any data as every time the page loads the server sends a `304`

my backend controller:

```
exports.getAllShoes = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let query = Shoe.find({});
    const shoes = await query.populate([
      {
        path: 'user',
        select: 'username',
      },
    ]);

    return res.status(200).json(shoes);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

app.js in my backend folder:

```
// ROUTES
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use(
  '/api',
  expressJwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET, algorithms: ['HS256'] })
);
app.use('/api/shoes', shoeRouter);
```

package.json in my `client` folder

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:9000"
```

My network preview:

[image: network preview]

Comment: I'd say the difference is the trailing slash then. Try using `userTokenAxios.get('');`

Comment: Just tried it, didn't do anything

Comment: Is port 3000 your React app? Have you set up a [proxy configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)? If so, what is it? What is your Express app's router config? How is the `getAllShoes` controller included in your app?

Comment: I added the code to the question. In case it helps, I have only been able to test `create` in my app and it works fine. so not all of the routes are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your interceptor. Response interceptors **must** return a value, a rejected promise or throw an error, otherwise the resulting promise will resolve with `undefined`.

It also seems odd that you're intercepting token errors in the successful response interceptor. I would have assumed you'd use the error interceptor.

```js
userTokenAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => res, // success response interceptor
  err => {
    // usually you'd look for a 401 status ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    if (err.response?.data?.errorMessage === "jwt expired") {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }

    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);
```

If you are actually responding with a 200 status for token errors, you'd need to handle it in the success interceptor

```js
userTokenAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {
    if (res.data.errorMessage === "jwt expired") {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      localStorage.removeItem('user');

      // Make this look like an Axios error
      return Promise.reject({
        message: "jwt expired",
        response: res,
      });
    }

    return res;
  }
);
```

It also looks like you don't need the trailing forward-slash in your request so simply use

```js
const response = await userTokenAxios.get("");
```

Comment: It's still returning a 304, but at least I have data now.